# How to trim the string using node.js?

Tags: jquery, node.js

I am trying to trim the string.  I google it for trim.

The tips i am getting.

1. name.trim();                    -- Not recognized trim() function
2. npm install --save string

   ```
          var S = require('string');
          S('hello ').trim().s;    -- this also same issue
   ```

Can you any one assist me what is the problem of the above method or anything i have missed it?

Comment: `name.trim()` should work if `name` is a string.

Comment: What's `typeof name`?

Comment: okay can you post that you have loaded the string dependency? i mean can you ensure that you have the string node module loaded.

Comment: In case this happens to anyone else like it just did for me (and since this is the #1 hit in google right now for "trim is not a function") here's the answer. You are probably working with a Buffer and not a string like you think you are. This is probably caused by accepting input from process.stdin without first calling process.stdin.setEncoding('utf8') or whatever encoding you need. If you don't set the encoding then stdin will return a Buffer object not a string, and trim() is not defined on Buffer. Set the encoding, or call .toString() on the input to convert the Buffer to a string first.

Answer (score 33, accepted):

You don't need jquery for this...

```
var str = "       Hello World!        ";
var trimmedStr = str.trim();
console.log(trimmedStr);
```

This will output the following in the console:

> "Hello World!"

Comment: It am getting correct after puting    "str.toString().trim();"

Comment: var is common? what are you talking about

Comment: If you don't know what javascript `var` is, please start here. http://www.w3schools.com/js/js_variables.asp

Comment: Actually Vanarajan is correct, since var can be of any type. In this situation var is a string, but it might be not a string in other situations.

Answer (score 1):

Try this work for me

```
var str = "  Hello World!    ";
var trim_leftright = str.replace(/^\s*|\s*$/g, ''); // left and right trim
console.log(trimleftright);

var trim_left = str.replace(/^\s*/, ''); // left trim
console.log(trim_left);

var trim_right = str.replace(/\s*$/, ''); // right trim
console.log(trim_right);
```

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to convert anything. From the Node.js console:

```
'    hello    '.trim()
```

works fine. It reduces to:

```
'hello'
```

as expected. You need only invoke the function on the string literal or a string variable.